# HTML Pattern for UK phone numbers

Tags: html, design-patterns, input

I need a pattern for my input that will accept the following style of numbers:

```
+44 7123456789 (13 Characters)
(01234) 123456 (11 Characters)
0 7123456789   (11 Characters)
```

The above patterns should be the only way the input is accepted so if they use a + character at the beginning the character count should be 13 or else if the first character is 0 it should be 11 characters long.

I don't personally understand how patterns are meant to be written so if you are creating your own custom one could you please explain what the code is doing or provide a link to the site you used to understand patterns.

Comment: Not all UK phone numbers have 10 national numbers in them.

Comment: Oh crap I completely forgot landline numbers, let me amend the question

Answer (score 2):

Good Day, i think it´s for a input,  if u like to use patterns you must work with html5, there is the cheat sheet http://html5pattern.com/Phones

in your case the option is:

`<input type="text" required="" pattern="^(?:0|\(?\+33\)?\s?|0033\s?)[1-79](?:[\.\-\s]?\d\d){4}$" value="" name="phones_pattern2" id="phones_pattern2" list="phones_pattern2_datalist" placeholder="Phone number.">`

Comment: While useful, the cheat sheet only accounts for mobile numbers. This isn't useful if you want to include landline numbers.